# How to use Twilio InitiateOutboundCall callback method?

Tags: vb.net, twilio

I can't figure out how to properly use the twilio REST client InitateOutboundCall(CallOptions, System.Action Of( Twilio.Call)

I want to create an outbound call, then use the callback to update the status in my application that the call created, or failed for some reason.

```
 Dim twil As New Twilio.TwilioRestClient(TwilioSID, TwilioPass)
        Dim Options = New Twilio.CallOptions()
        Options.Url = "http://something"
        Options.To = "+123456789"
        Options.From = "+123456789"
        Options.Record = True
        Options.StatusCallback = "http://callbackurl"
        Dim TwilResult = twil.InitiateOutboundCall(Options, System.Action (Of Twilio.Call) )
```

I don't understand how to use the System.Action (Of Twilio.Call). The documentation says: callback as System.Action(Of Twilio.Call); method to call upon successful completion. But i can't just pass it a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a method that matches the signature of the delegate that is expected:

```
Private Sub HandleCall(objCall As Twilio.Call)

    'Implementation

End Sub
```

Then use [AddressOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74wy9422(v=vs.90).aspx) referencing the HandleCall subroutine:

```
Dim TwilResult = twil.InitiateOutboundCall(Options, AddressOf HandleCall)
```

Or you can use a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
Dim TwilResult = twil.InitiateOutboundCall(Options, Sub(objCall As Twilio.Call)
                                                      'Implementation
                                                    End Sub)
```